# Does the Cyclomatic Complexity extension exist for ReSharper 9.1?

Tags: resharper, resharper-9.1

I was trying Resharper 9.1 and I've found no cyclomatic complexity setting ...I've searched on plugins but as far I've seen it works with PowerToys till the 8.3

Am I missing it or has it been removed?

Comment: It hasn't been updated to 9.1 yet (or 9.0 for that matter). I'll get it updated sometime this week, hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [ReSharper PowerToys: Cyclomatic Complexity extension](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/PowerToys.CyclomaticComplexity) has not been updated for over a year now. I would suggest contacting Jetbrains and ask them if it will be updated for 9.1.

In the mean time you could use Visual Studio's `Analyze`->`Calculate Code Metrics for Solution` to show you your Cyclomatic Complexity.

Answer (score 3):

It's been updated to 9.2, you can download it from the Extension Manager. It works for C#, VB, Javascript, TypeScript + C++.

Here's [a screenshot](https://twitter.com/citizenmatt/status/636830315227541504), [release notes](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-cyclomatic-complexity/releases/tag/v9.2.0) and [readme](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-cyclomatic-complexity#readme).